# APISix error installing using Docker on M1 Pro

Tags: docker, apple-m1, apache-apisix

I keep getting this response when I run APISix docker install command. How do I solve this?
I am installing on M1 Pro:

```
[MacBook-Pro-2 example % docker-compose -p docker-apisix -f docker-compose-arm64.yml up -d
[+] Running 0/15
 ⠦ web2 Pulling                                                                                                                     4.6s
   ⠙ 595b0fe564bb Pulling fs layer                                                                                                  1.1s
   ⠋ ba46c7763ab7 Pulling fs layer                                                                                                  1.1s
   ⠋ 4a6e4fa08bae Pulling fs layer                                                                                                  1.1s
   ⠋ 5fcff24516c7 Waiting                                                                                                           1.1s
   ⠋ aec49f82b3a2 Waiting                                                                                                           1.1s
   ⠋ e04efcbce226 Waiting                                                                                                           1.1s
 ⠦ etcd Pulling                                                                                                                     4.6s
   ⠋ 9f9ba9541db2 Waiting                                                                                                           1.0s
   ⠋ 250181cef7de Waiting                                                                                                           1.0s
   ⠋ 7e281caa7d91 Waiting                                                                                                           1.0s
   ⠋ 3375dc7c185a Waiting                                                                                                           1.0s
   ⠋ be512cf3202c Waiting                                                                                                           1.0s
 ⠿ apisix Error                                                                                                                     4.6s
 ⠦ web1 Pulling                                                                                                                     4.6s
Error response from daemon: manifest for apache/apisix:2.99.0-alpine not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/apisix/tags

It doesn't have `2.99.0-alpine` tag.

You can try to use `apache/apisix:2.99.0-debian` or `apache/apisix:2.99.0-centos`